# Order posts by custom field DATE value

Tags: query, advanced-custom-fields, get-posts, order

Hello I need to order posts by custom field date value, so for example:2022, 2021,2020

```
<?php 

// get posts
$posts = get_posts(array(
    'post_type'         => 'events',
    'post_status'=> 'publish',
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'meta_key'          => 'event_start',
    'orderby'           => 'meta_value',
    'order'             => 'DESC'
));

if( $posts ): ?>
    
    <ul>
        
    <?php foreach( $posts as $post ): 
        
        setup_postdata( $post )
        
        ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?> (date: <?php the_field('event_start'); ?>)</a>
        </li>
    
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    
    </ul>
    
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

my custom field value is save format is: 26032020 day,month,year
but I am getting wrong sort (see image)[image]

Comment: `26032020` is not sortable as a date. You need to use another format. Something like `YYYYMMDD` is sortable, because a later date is always larger, eg. `20200326`.

Comment: that's not a standard date storage format, Jacob is right, you need to use a standard date format that MySQL understands, such as seconds since 1971 or an ISO standard date such as `2020-03-26`

Comment: Also, by using `get_posts` you need to set `suppress_filters` to false or it won't use caching and you'll get a performance penalty. Likewise, setting posts_per_page too `-1` is dangerous, set it to a high number you never expect to reach or paginate that you know the server can handle, but never `infinite/-1`. A good guide is an upper limit of 100, no user will be able to processs that many without another page anyway, but more importantly, very few servers can process that many.

Comment: understoo now..